# How to preserve order of columns in cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax

I have two tables in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
          name text PRIMARY KEY,
          grade text, 
          labid List<int>);

CREATE TABLE table2(
          name text PRIMARY KEY,
          deptid List<int>  
          grade text,);
```

for example:

```
val result: RDD[String, String, List[Int]] = myFunction();
result.saveToCassandra(keyspace, table1)
```

It is working fine.
but in case of using below line:

```
result.saveToCassandra(keyspace, table2)
```

m getting this type of error : com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConversionException: Cannot convert object test_data of type class java.lang.String to List[AnyRef]

Is there any solution using SomeColumns which satisfy the both tables[we don't know which table will be executed]. eg:

```
result.saveToCassandra(keyspace, table, SomeColumns(....))?
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the dataframe schema only cares about position, not column name, so if your c* table has a different column order, you will get incorrect writes. The solution is like you said, to use `SomeColumns`.

```
val columns = dataFrame.schema.map(_.name: ColumnRef)    
dataFrame.rdd.saveToCassandra(keyspaceName, tableName, SomeColumns(columns: _*))
```

Now the dataframe columns will be written to c* using their name, not position.

Answer (score 0):

You arguments should be in different order because the tables have different column types:

```
val result: RDD[String, String, List[Int]] = myFunction();
val reorder: RDD[String, List[Int], String] = result.map(r => r._1, r._3, r._2)
reorder.saveToCassandra(keyspace, table2)
```

Comment: Yes, I know your solution. but Is there any other solution?

Comment: Is there SomeColumns will be usefull?